# Tag game on graphs

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096721/rabbit-inside-a-cube-with-three-hunters/4096893).

> This game is played on an arbitrary graph. Player 1 starts by choosing a vertex. Then alternate:
>
> 1. Player 2 selects a set of $n$ vertices of the graph. Player 1 loses if they are on any of these.
> 2. Otherwise, player 1 moves from their current vertex to one of its neighbours. Player 2 learns nothing other than that the game hasn't ended.
>
> What is the minimum $n$ such that player 2 wins?

WOLOG, the graph is connected and simple. As [@Tavish](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/751311/tavish) notes, the only way to make progress is to completely eliminate vertices; but the eliminated set need not be monotonic per turn. $n$ itself is monotonic under induced subgraphs.

Several interesting cases to consider:

1. The infinite star: $n=1$
2. $k$ triangles joined at a common vertex (or the $2k$-star, with leaves paired): $n=2$
3. Two infinite stars with their roots connected: $n=1$
4. The $k$-path, $k\geq5$: <s>n=2</s> $n=1$ still
5. The 5-cycle with one vertex exploded into $k$ unconnected vertices: $n=2$
6. The $k$-cycle, $k\geq6$: <s>n=3</s> $n=2$ still
7. An induced subgraph of minimum degree $k$: $n\geq k$

So it seems path length plays a complicated role here, not just degree.

Here's an easy upper bound:

> Arbitrarily order the vertices. Maintain two sets, called the *burned* set and the *current-tag* set; both start out empty.
>
> 1. Pick the earliest unburned vertex, and add it and its unburned neighbours to the current-tag set.
> 2. Tag all of the current-tag set this turn.
> 3. Whenever a vertex and all its neighbours are all either burned or currently-tagged, burn that vertex and remove it from the current-tag set.
> 4. Repeat.
>
> Correctness invariant: player 1 may never be on a burned vertex.

Any stronger theorems?

Comment: [Finding a princess in a palace: A pursuit-evasion problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5490) solves the problem completely for $n=1$.

Comment: So I didn't check turn 3 of the $5$-path carefully enough eh

Comment: Yeah, it's rather marvelous that the $n$-path can be solved no matter how big $n$ is.

Comment: Well, given the correct name, found [On Evasion Games on Graphs](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-48532-4_23). Unfortunately, I'm no longer affiliated with an *academic* institution, so I can't check what they mean by an evasion game.

Comment: Here is is, on the author's professional web site: http://www.eda.ict.e.titech.ac.jp/ueno/Files/papers/TU16-LNCS_9943.pdf